# SQL installer seems to not working

Tags: php, sql

I am developing an custom extension following this guide: http://tutorialsformagento.blogspot.in/2014/06/add-custom-fields-to-order-and-quote.html

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_Vshipping>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </VivasIndustries_Vshipping>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>          
            <!-- <vshipping>
                 <use>standard</use>
                 <args>
                     <module>VivasIndustries_Vshipping</module>
                     <frontName>party</frontName>
                 </args>
             </vshipping>-->
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <vshipping>
                    <file>vshipping.xml</file>
                </vshipping>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <vshipping>
                    <file>vivasindustries/vshipping.xml</file>
                </vshipping>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <events>
            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
                <observers>
                    <checkout>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>VivasIndustries_Vshipping_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customDataSave</method>
                    </checkout>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
            <sales_quote_save_before> <!-- Name of Event -->
                <observers>
                    <save_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>VivasIndustries_Vshipping_Model_Observer</class>
                        <!-- Over Model Class -->
                        <method>saveQuoteBefore</method>
                        <!-- name of function -->
                    </save_before>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_save_before>
        </events>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>VivasIndustries_Vshipping_Model_Sales_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
            <vshipping>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshipping_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>vshipping_resource</resourceModel>
            </vshipping>
            <vshipping_resource>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshipping_Model_Resource</class>
            </vshipping_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <vshipping_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>VivasIndustries_Vshipping</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </vshipping_setup>
            <vshipping_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </vshipping_read>
            <vshipping_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </vshipping_write>
        </resources>
        <blocks>

            <vshipping>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshipping_Block</class>
            </vshipping>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <vshipping>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshipping_Helper</class>
            </vshipping>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is my: /sql/vshipping_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php:

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
require_once('app/Mage.php');
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'backend_type' => 'varchar',
    'frontend_input' => 'varchar',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label' => 'Delivery Date',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => '0',
    'comparable' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false
);
$installer->addAttribute('order','vshipping_account_no',$attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('quote','vshipping_account_no',$attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('order','vshipping_phone_no',$attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('quote','vshipping_phone_no',$attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('order','vshipping_comment',$attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('quote','vshipping_comment',$attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

However when i export my whole database with PHPMyAdmin and i search for `vshipping_account_no` there is no result found.

It seems this sql installer is not creating this mysql changes.

Where is my mistake and how can i fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a quick glance,  *your module version number in the config.xml and the setup version number in the setup install script file name doesn't match*.

> mysql4-install-**1.0.0**.php should be mysql4-install-**0.1.0**.php

And you can keep your setup file as simple as shown below. I can find too many unnecessary lines in your setup file.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();    
$installer->addAttribute("order", "vshipping_account_no", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "vshipping_account_no", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute('order','vshipping_phone_no', array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute('quote','vshipping_phone_no', array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute('order','vshipping_comment', array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute('quote','vshipping_comment', array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Above all, this SO thread below should be a great help to get this done.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento